# too many indices for array for numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

When I am trying to print every entry in a ndarray, I use this:

```
    A = np.array([[(1,2,3)],
             [1,2,3],
             [1,2,3]])

     dim = len(A)
     for i in range(dim):
         for j in range(dim):
             print(A[i,j])
```

however it shows that :too many indices for array
where do I wrong?

Comment: The array you construct is *non-sensical* since the first list contains *one* element: a tuple. As a result, numpy makes a 1d array of `object`s.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, I see what is the correct way to do that ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the tuple in your numpy array:

```
A = np.array([[(1,2,3)],
              [1,2,3],
              [1,2,3]])
```

This thus means that the first sublist contains *one* element: a 3-tuple. Since not these lists contains a different number of elements, numpy will contruct a **1D** array of objects:

```
>>> A
array([list([(1, 2, 3)]), list([1, 2, 3]), list([1, 2, 3])], dtype=object)
```

so the array is simply a 1D array of references to `object`s, these objects *can* be lists, but these can be anything. So as a result, there is only *one* dimension that can be indexed.

If we omit the round brackets, we have a list of three elements, like:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],
...               [1,2,3],
...               [1,2,3]])
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

and then querying with two indices is no problem at all.